# Why can anyone with a valid idToken run arbitrary REST API calls on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How can you prevent anyone who got hold of an `idToken` from running arbitrary commands against your Firebase project?

Let's say I have a website using Firebase services through the JS interface: functions used here might be authentication and Firestore.

While this is an edge-case of clear abuse, any user of your web application who retrieves the `idToken` (after authentication) can run REST commands against your services, including **updating their own email** without you knowing about that Firebase-side change. All they need is to grab the `idToken` and the `web api key`, which is [not a private concept](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys).

As I understand, there are ways to limit the quotas of your APIs, but I haven't found a way to turn off specific endpoints. How do you stop users from playing with their own data - or am I misunderstanding anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has a user's idToken it means that either he is the user and he has signed-in or he has received the idToken from a signed-in user. This is the case for any authentication system and we cannot prevent a user sharing the idToken, or much easier, sharing his/her credentials with someone else.

And yes, with the idToken and the Project API key a user can update his email by calling the [`updateEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#updateemail) method or by issuing an HTTP POST request to the [`setAccountInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-change-email) endpoint exposed by the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth). AFAIK there isn't any way to prevent that when using the default Firebase email/password authentication provider. This is a choice made by Firebase which, somehow, considers that the user is the full owner of his personal info.

Note however that when a user calls this method:

1. An email "will be sent to the original email address (if it was set) that allows to revoke the email address change, in order to protect them from account hijacking".
2. Calling this method is "a security sensitive operation that requires the user to have recently signed in".

---

An alternative solution is to [integrate Firebase Authentication with a custom authentication system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) in such a way you fully control the possibilities to change the user account details.

Comment: Thanks Renaud!!! We do use custom authentication and could add claims, but I have not found out, yet, how to limit the possibilities as you describe above.

Comment: AFAIK if you use custom authentication (i.e. you have your own authentication server which creates custom token) the `updateEmail()` method should not work. Claims don't have any effect on the `updateEmail()`, they are to be used in Security Rules (Firestore, Cloud Storage, etc.) or in Callable Cloud Functions.

Comment: Our client signs in with a custom token, receives an idToken from Firebase and is then able to change their email using that very token - I tried and it worked. Also, that "exploit" could be used to find out who else is registered there using the error responses, so I still think it's an open door that should be closed?!